# How to change the height of MUI Datepicker input box in MUI Material v6

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Paper elevation={0}>
  <DatePicker
    fullWidth
    views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
    openTo='month'
    value={initialDate}
    slotProps={{ textField: { sx: { height: '10px' } } }}
    onChange={(newValue) => handleInitialDateChange(newValue)}
  />
</Paper>
```

I have the above code. For some reason the `height` property I passed via `sx` via `textField` via `slotProps` is only affecting the `Paper` component.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly hack that I found after a bit of documentation dumpster diving is this:

```
sx={{
  '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
    height: '43px',
  },
}}
```

The component looks like this:

```
<Paper elevation={0}>
  <DatePicker
    fullWidth
    views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
    openTo='month'
    value={finalDate}
    sx={{
      '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
        height: '43px',
      },
    }}
    onChange={(newValue) => handleFinalDateChange(newValue)}
  />
</Paper>
```

I would really appreciate a better way to do this, though. If there isn't, well I guess its time I put in a feature request for the MUI team.